# How can I define a Python function to return a square wave instead of an array?

Tags: python, function, scipy, user-defined-functions

I am using square wave signal in Python as `signal.square()` which returns an array. However, I'm curious if I can define a square wave *function*. Meaning, obviously, it would return numbers(instead of an array) according to my input.

For reference, the following is the snippet which consists of my naive attempt. The code of course doesn't work but hopefully will help understand what I'm aiming for here.

```py
from scipy import signal as sig
t=np.linspace(0,1,1000)
x=np.full(size,0)
SQ=sig.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * t)
for i,c in enumerate(t):
    if((c%TP)<=t_F):
        Sum+=np.random.normal(0,1)*math.sqrt(d)
    elif((c%TP)>t_F):
         Sum+=np.random.normal(0,1)*math.sqrt(d)+SQ[Sum]
    x[i]=Sum
```

Obviously, SQ is an array here, so SQ[Sum] doesn't make sense as Sum is of the type float. So, what I'm looking for, once again, is a *square wave* function (say, SQ itself) which I can call in place of SQ[Sum](as in the snippet).

Comment: "I am using square wave signal in python. It obviously returns an array." Why is that obvious?

Comment: Doesn't `signal.square()` return an array?

Comment: I don't doubt that it is true, but not every true thing is *obviously* true. I don't see how the word "obviously" adds anything to that sentence.

Comment: The main difficulty with your question is it's not at all clear what your goal is.  You say you want it to "return numbers(instead of an array)".  But what does that mean?  What's the difference between "returning numbers" and returning an array that contains numbers?

Comment: @JohnColeman True. I take it back. However, I can't edit it out anymore, for it is not substantial enough. Sorry! Let's look beyond it.

Comment: Also, a general tip:  "code snippets" which give no context for the external libraries involved (in this case, numpy and scipy) tend to confuse instead of clarify.  Especially so since base Python has a module named "signal".

Comment: @JDM I'm sorry if my question is unclear. What I mean here is I want a function, say F(x) that returns values like a square wave would. So, if I call F(x) where x would be of the type float, it should return a number.

Comment: @JDM I have edited my snippet a bit. Please, have a look now.

Comment: `t_F`, `TP` and `d` appear to be undefined

Comment: Does scipy.signal.square() accept a single-element array as input?  You can try setting t as `t = [0.001]`, or `t = [0.197]`, etc. as an experiment to see what it does with that input.  If it accepts a single-element array and returns the corresponding value, that's your solution.

Comment: @SiHa I thought including their definitions would be irrelevant to my question. Nonetheless, all three of them are just constants of type float.

Comment: @All turns what I was looking for was embarrassingly trivial. It was the following, 
```def SQ(pos):
    return signal.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * pos)
```
Now, `SQ(x)`, where x is any float number, returns a number as I wanted. Sorry to bother you all with my ill-framed question! Thanks for the cooperation.